# key event calls action more then once

Tags: javascript, jsf

My scenario is  to display a modal pop up with YES and NO Button.
either clicking Yes button or pressing "Y" it should performed desired action and similarly for No button.

`MyXhtml.xhtml`

```
    <a4j:outputPanel id="panelForButton" >
    <h:outputText id="errorMsg" name="errorMsg"  class="pop_outputText" value="#{demoBean.messages}" />
                    <a4j:commandButton id ="btnOne" 
                                       action="#{demoBean.yesAction}" 
                                       value="YES" 
                                       reRender="panelOne,paneltwo"
                                       oncomplete="closePOPUP()">   
                    </a4j:commandButton>



                    <a4j:commandButton id ="btnTwo" 
                                       action="#{demoBean.noAction}" 
                                       value="No"
                                       reRender="panelOne,paneltwo" 
                                       oncomplete="closePOPUP()">   
                    </a4j:commandButton>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
```

jquery function

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function (e) {

        if (e.which == 89) {
            alert(" Y pressed ");
            //document.getElementById('btnOne').click();
        }
        if (e.which == 78) {
            alert(" N pressed ");
            //document.getElementById('btnTwo').click();
        }


});
```

but the problem i am facing is whenever i press 'Y' or 'N'. it calls alert message 3 times  i.e  it invokes my respective actions 3 times (i have comment out my button click).

when i click "Yes" or  "No" button  it  calls alert only once and which is expected.

Comment: In other words, that jQuery code snippet as whole has been executed 3 times? In other words, you effectively ended up with 3 keydown listeners? Have you embedded it in the JSF page as part of a section which gets ajax-updated 2 times or so?

Comment: actually this is a pop up box inside my xhtml.  but even if it is ajax updated, button click sholudn't be called  twice or thrice ?

Comment: Ugh. Put JS code in a JS file, not a XHTML file. This problem will then solve all by itself.

Comment: hi Balu, could you please explain why 3 listeners will be created.?

Comment: Because you (indirectly) executed that whole `jQuery(document)...` script 3 times on the same HTML document. If that script was enclosed in an element which is ajax-updated by JSF, then it will obviously be re-executed on each ajax update. If that element is ajax-updated twice, then you effectively end up with a total of 3 same listeners on the document.

Comment: Hi Balu, i have moved all javscript code to an external file but ,  it is invoking now 2 times . is there any way to restrict this  ?

Comment: Include that JS file 1 time, not 2 times.

Comment: thanks a lot Balu, it worked !!!